# In Grails can we access methods without creation of objects?

Tags: grails

as I am new to grails but I am familiar with Java.In the following code I have Artist domain class and ArtistController class. In controller class the Artist accessing the findByName(...) directly I mean its not creating the object to access the method (or) is findByName(..)  a static method so that it can be accessed using the className.staticMethodName as in Java.

```
class ArtistController {
def show() {
def artist = Artist.findByName(params.artistName)
// do whatever is appropriate with the artist...
}
}
```

Comment: findByName is a static method.

Comment: Just like in Java, you can access static methods (the findBy* methods are static).

Comment: what's your question then?

Comment: Now I knew that findBy* all are static methods Joshua Moore and Lalit Agarwal make your comments as answers so that I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to `static` methods.  It has nothing to do with Grails vs Java, as `static` is present in Java also.  You may want to check out the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), but in a nutshell, a static method belongs to the `class`, and not an instance of that class, which is why you are able to invoke the method without a new object.